# What is the best way of making columns using bootstrap that I can apply to my code?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wlTMtUBxxsM) tutorial on youtube and when it came time to view my work and align the text with the icons horizontally, they remained stacked. What is an alternate way to use bootstraps grid system to align them horizontally instead of stacked on top of each other? I'm at a lost at how to fix this mess, it seems the tutorial was more for intermediate level coders.

```css
body {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: arial,helveitca,sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #dcdde1; 
}

.container{
    width:80%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* ------------ header ----------  */

header {
background: #7f8fa6;
color: #ffffff;
padding-top: 30px;
min-height: 70px;
border-bottom: #192a56 3px solid;
}


header a{
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size:16px;
    
}

header li {
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

header #branding {
    float:left;
}

header #branding h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

header nav {
    float:right;
    margin-top:10px;
}

header .highlight, header .current a {
    color: #40739e;
    font-weight: bold;
}

header a:hover{
    color:#cccccc;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/*-----------showcase------------*/

#showcase {
    min-height: 400px;
 background:url(../images/laptop.png);
     background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
}

#showcase h1 {
    margin-top:100px;
    font-size:55px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#showcase p {
    font-size: 20px;
}

/*-----------newsletter--------------*/

#newsletter {
    padding:15px;
    color:white;
    background: #7f8fa6
}

#newsletter h1{
    float:left;
}

#newsletter form {
    float:right;
    margin:15px;
}

#newsletter input[type="email"]{
    padding:4px;
    height:40px;
    width: 250px;
}

.button_1{
    height:40px;
    background-color: #fbc531;
    border:0;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    color:#353637;
}

#boxes {
    margin-top: 20px;
    
}

#boxes .box {
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    width:30%;
    padding:10px;
}

footer {
    padding:20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color:white;
    background:7f8fa6;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="Affordable Web Design For Small and Medium-sized Companies">
    <meta name="author" content="Keith Segovia">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css-master/normalize.css">
    
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mainfollow.css" type="text/css">

    <title>Youtube Tutorial 1</title>

  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="branding">
          <h1>
            <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i> <span class="highlight">1-2-3</span> Web Design
          </h1>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>

    </header>
    <section id="showcase">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Affordable Web Design For Small and Medium-sized Companies</h1>
        <p>d stamp, an am rudely strut befor made to court an amber To this fair proportive to deep bounting upon of the souls of York; And now, insteadful merry merry mer bruised fore our bruised fright the capers nimbly instern al.</p>
      </div>

    </section>

    <section id="newsletter">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Get Our Newsletter</h1>
        <form action="">
          <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email here">
          <button type="submit" class="button_1">Subscribe
                 
             </button>
        </form>

      </div>

    </section>

    <section id="boxes">
      <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
       
        <div class="box"><i class="fa fa-signal fa-5x"></i>
          <h3>Grow Your Audience</h3>
          <p>Really unusual yes out designed there let then create up. Articles shivers. Elsewhere worrying i'm much yeeucch furry teachers there. Non-native fears away relevant feel look. </p>
          </div>
           </div>
           </div>
            </div>
            
        <div class="container">
          <div class="box "><i class="fa fa-photo fa-5x"></i>
           
            <h3>Modern Web Design</h3>
            <p>Really unusual yes out designed there let then create up. Articles shivers. Elsewhere worrying i'm much yeeucch furry teachers there. Non-native fears away relevant feel look. </p>
             </div>
              </div>
            

          <div class="container">
            <div class="box"><i class="fa fa-cube fa-5x"></i>
               <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
              <h3>Ultra Fast Hosting</h3>
              <p>Really unusual yes out designed there let then create up. Articles shivers. Elsewhere worrying i'm much yeeucch furry teachers there. Non-native fears away relevant feel look. </p>
            </div>
             </div>
              </div>
               </div>
               

      </section>



    <footer>
    <p>1-2-3 Web Design Copyright &copy; 2019</p>
    </footer>



    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you recommend us to watch the tutorial to understand the problem?

Comment: I was hoping there was some glaring mistake I made, I wouldn't say its necessary, no need to

Comment: I believe this link contains very useful info what you'r looking for. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/

Comment: so I realized I was adding a new row when only one was necessary each line. Thanks for your helpful reference, much appreciated

Comment: Glad to hear that it was able to help you. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create columns using bootstrap

step 1-create container.

step 2-create row inside the container.

step 3-create columns (while using grid system screen divided into 12 columns).

so if you want to create 3 equals columns then col-md-4 + col-md-4 + col-md-4= 12columns

if want to create 2 equal columns then col-md-6 + col-md-6 = 12 columns

if you want to create column of different size create part according to choice
(for eg want to create 2 different column do like this col-md-4 + col-md-8 =12 columns)
this is the approach we always follow while creating bootstrap columns
I hope you will understand what I want to say.

```html
<section id="boxes">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        hello
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        hello
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        hello
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Now I"m having the issue of making columns that slide over as more text is put in. Any idea why that is?

Comment: can you please show me the problem so I can find out the issue easily

Comment: Its just overflow of text in the columns. I want word-wrap but not sure how I can get that done

Comment: style="word-wrap: break-word"

Comment: try this one and use overflow to hidden